# selection to copy and paste error

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently trying to find the data I need by find as I do not know where it is located and then copy the data down the column onto another sheet. I need to do this multiple times.

However, I keep getting the error of Object Variable or With block Variable not set on my second find, it's on the line:

```
.range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

**My Code**

```
Dim ran, r As range
With Sheet2
    Set ran = .Cells.find(What:="User Defined Label 4", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ran.Select
   .range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheet9.range("A1").PasteSpecial

    Set r = .Cells.find(What:="V Align", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    r.Select
    .range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheet9.range("B1").PasteSpecial
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few comments regarding you code:

**1.**`Dim ran, r As range` means `ran` is `Variant`, and only `r` is `Range`.

**2.** No need to have:

```
ran.Select
.range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

Just use fully qualifed `Range` without any `Select`ing:

```
.Range(Ran, Ran.End(xlDown)).Copy
```

**3.** Make sure your `Find` was able to find the string/value you were looking for, add `If Not Ran Is Nothing Then`.

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UseFind()

Dim Ran As Range, r As Range

With Sheet2
    Set Ran = .Cells.Find(What:="User Defined Label 4", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Not Ran Is Nothing Then ' <-- make sure Find was successful
        .Range(Ran, Ran.End(xlDown)).Copy
        Sheet9.Range("A1").PasteSpecial
    End If

    ' add your second "Find" here

End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: Oh i thought ran and r would be the same ! Wasn't v sure of how to use range object so I jus pluck the codes from online ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: Yes, it is working ! Can I ask how do go using find to not use exact match

Comment: @RachelChia change `LookAt:=xlWhole` to `LookAt:=xlPart`

Comment: Thanks for always helping. You're the best haha